# Error when executing a "where" inside a function type "udf" - Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to execute a udf function and it returns an error

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

mytab = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="mytab",properties=connectionProperties)

def buscarx(Alm_r, Pro, Data_mat):
    data_s = mytab.where(col("doc")==Data_mat).where(col("alm")!=Alm_r).limit(1)
    if(data_s.count()==0):
        return Pro
    else:
        temp = "0"
        for item in data_s.collect():
            temp = data_s.Alm
        return temp

buscarx_udf = udf(buscarx)
df_temp = mytab.withColumn("alm_origen", buscarx_udf(mytab.Alm,mytab.Proveedor,mytab.Doc_mat))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 473, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 563, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

I ran some tests and found that the problem is caused by:

```py
    data_s = mytab.where(col("doc")==Data_mat).where(col("alm")!=Alm_r).limit(1)
```

Any suggestions to fix this? I need to perform a query within the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference a dataframe when in an UDF on another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390572/how-to-reference-a-dataframe-when-in-an-udf-on-another-dataframe)

Comment: UDFs are required to be in pure python. meaning, you can't use sql functions and reference spark dataframes or RDDs directly.

Comment: Some alternative?

Answer (score 1):

A USER DEFINED FUNCTION operates on data within a dataframe and not on the dataframe as a whole like spark sql functions. Hence you cannot use pyspark sql methods like where, filter etc.

Comment: Any alternative that allows me to achieve the proposed?